# DB2 FOR Cursor Inside Trigger Error

Tags: database, db2, cursor

I am trying to loop through a list of trip_numbers in my table. Whenever I try using a FOR loop, I get the following error:

ERROR: An unexpected token "CURSOR" was found following "cur1". Expected tokens may include: "JOIN ". SQLSTATE-42601

```
CREATE TRIGGER SCHEMA.UPDATE_OP_CODE_2 

AFTER UPDATE OF USER1 ON TLORDER 

REFERENCING NEW AS N 

FOR EACH ROW 

MODE DB2SQL 

BEGIN ATOMIC 

DECLARE mTRIP_NUMBER INTEGER; --

FOR v AS cur1 CURSOR FOR (SELECT TRIP_NUMBER FROM ITRIPTLO WHERE 
DETAIL_LINE_ID  =  N.DETAIL_LINE_ID)--

DO
SET mTRIP_NUMBER  = cur1.TRIP_NUMBER;

IF (mTRIP_NUMBER IS NOT NULL AND mTRIP_NUMBER != 0) THEN 

    CALL DF_SAVELEGINTERSECTION(mTRIP_NUMBER, 'True'); --

    CALL OPTIMIZE_CARRIER(mTRIP_NUMBER); --

    CALL DF_CALCULATETRIPTOTALS(mTRIP_NUMBER, 'True'); --

END IF; --
END FOR;
END
```

Can I not use a FOR Loop/cursor inside a trigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the "cur1 CURSOR FOR". This is not supported for "inlined compound" of trigger.

```
  CREATE TRIGGER SCHEMA.UPDATE_OP_CODE_2 

  AFTER UPDATE OF USER1 ON TLORDER 

  REFERENCING NEW AS N 

  FOR EACH ROW 

  MODE DB2SQL 

  BEGIN ATOMIC 

    DECLARE mTRIP_NUMBER INTEGER; --

    FOR v AS (SELECT TRIP_NUMBER FROM ITRIPTLO WHERE DETAIL_LINE_ID  =  N.DETAIL_LINE_ID)--

    DO

      SET mTRIP_NUMBER  = TRIP_NUMBER;--

      IF (mTRIP_NUMBER IS NOT NULL AND mTRIP_NUMBER != 0) THEN 

        CALL DF_SAVELEGINTERSECTION(mTRIP_NUMBER, 'True'); --

        CALL OPTIMIZE_CARRIER(mTRIP_NUMBER); --

        CALL DF_CALCULATETRIPTOTALS(mTRIP_NUMBER, 'True'); --

      END IF; --

    END FOR;--

  END
```